# java Modification error

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx-8

I want to loop through an arraylist to see wheather the p.name(Player name) is equal to what ever the user type in a text-box; when I enter a value it work for the first name but when I change the value in the text-box it throw a concurrent modification error.

Company class

```
 public class Company {

  int shares = 100;
  ArrayList <Player> shareHolders = new ArrayList<>();

  if (condition()) {
    for (Player p: company.shareHolders) { // error highlight this line
            if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase(txtname.getText()) && 
                    (company.shares <= 100 && company.shares >0)) {

                    company.shares -= Integer.parseInt(txtShares.getText());
                    p.shares += Integer.parseInt(txtShares.getText());
                    System.out.println(p.name+":"+p.shares+" | Company"+company.shares);
                    return;
                }else{
                    company.shareHolders.add(new Player(txtname.getText()));
                    System.out.println(txtname.getText()+" added");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a new list of it

Comment: And shouldn't your `else` have a `break`?

Comment: JacobG, I found the answer to it. really appreciate your help

Comment: can I use something like this:                                                                 for (Player p: new ArrayList<Player>(company.shareHolders)) {

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying `company.shareHolders` during an iteration over it, which is not allowed (hence the `ConcurrentModificationException`).

Comment: any clue on how to get over this problem